# Android NDK - Library not found

Tags: android, android-ndk

I work with Android Studio and Android NDK.
My folder "src/main/jni" contains the following files:

- Android.mk
- Application.mk
- HelloWorld.cpp

Application.mk
`APP_ABI := all`

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := HelloWorld
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := HelloWorld.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

In my Java code, I load the library:

```
static{
    System.load("HelloWorld");
}
```

I run ndk-build as below and it runs without error: `ndk-build -C src/main`

build.gradle contains:

```
sourceSets.main {
jniLibs.srcDirs 'src/main/libs'
jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}
```

libHelloWorld.so is compiled and copied to the folders:`app\src\main\libs\arm*\`

The root directory of app-debug.apk contains a lib directory. 
libHelloWorld.so exists in all subdirectories (lib\arm*)

When I deploy and debug the application on the LG Nexus 4 device, I get the following error:

```
9-24 18:50:51.486  20352-20352/ndk.tests.firstndk E/art﹕ dlopen("HelloWorld", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "HelloWorld" not found
09-24 18:50:51.489  20352-20352/ndk.tests.firstndk D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-24 18:50:51.491  20352-20352/ndk.tests.firstndk E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ndk.tests.firstndk, PID: 20352
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "HelloWorld" not found
at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:331)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:981)
at ndk.tests.firstndk.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:11)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
```

Could you please help to solve this issue? Why my native lib cannot be loaded? What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works ! Such a long wasted time for such a small mistake... Thank you so much!